# Jenkins Slave - The specified working directory should be fully accessible to the remoting executable RWX

Tags: linux, jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am getting below error while launching a slave node from jenkins master.

**Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The specified working directory should be fully accessible to the remoting executable (RWX):**

```
[07/07/21 18:10:40] [SSH] Starting agent process: cd "/home/user" && /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java  -jar remoting.jar -workDir /home/user

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The specified working directory should be fully accessible to the remoting executable (RWX): /home/user

at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager.verifyDirectory(WorkDirManager.java:249)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager.initializeWorkDir(WorkDirManager.java:201)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:322)
    at hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:298)
Slave JVM has terminated. Exit code=1
[07/07/21 18:10:40] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[07/07/21 18:10:40] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

I tried some solutions;

- User permissions and file permissions provided
- Java home is correctly updated
- Slave configuration is also fine

Slave launch screenshot [image: slave-logs-picture]

Please help me to know if I am missing anything important in my slave setting before launching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for this issues was very easy, the problem was I mistakenly created a user from root with root's permissions set on /home/user directory.

changed the users home directory permission to username:group and it worked fine.

```
sudo chmod -R user:groupid /home/user
```

or

```
sudo chmod -R 777 user:groupid /directory-path
```

Please note this user has been used on slave machine configuration of Jenkins so the permissions should be sufficient to access workspace.

Comment: I see error in response over console - chmod -R 777 user:groupid /home/slave1
chmod: cannot access 'user:groupid': No such file or directory - @nabeel can you please help me with this.

Comment: @NaseerAhammed please check if user and group is existing and directory as well